# При добавлении объектов, в конечном итоге все объекты принимают одинаковое значение, как сделать так чтобы ранее веденные задания оставались?

Tags: javascript, jquery

После добавления задания, все задания принимают его (последнее) значение. Не могу понять почему.

```html
    <pre>
    <head>
        <h1>Список дел</h1>
    </head>
    <section>
        <input type="text" name="task" id="task" value="Задание">
        <div class="btn-block">
        <button id="add_btn" class="add-task btn">Добавить</button>
        <button id="show_btn" class="show-task btn">Отобразить</button>
        </div>
        <div id="result"> Элемент был добавлен</div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let count = 0;
        $("#add_btn").on('click',function(){
            let task = $("input").val()
            count++;
            $("#result").css("display", "block");
            setTimeout( function(){$("#result").hide()}, 2000);
            $('<div>').attr({'class':'add_item'}).css({'display':'none'}).insertAfter ("#result");
                $(".add_item").html("<h1>"+'Задание #'+count+' ' +task+"</h1>").appendTo($('.block'));   

        });
        $("#show_btn").on('click',function(){
            $(".add_item").css("display", "block");
        });
    </script>
    <!--$('body').append('<p>This is the text in new element.<p>');
    $(".add_item").html("<h1>"+'Задание #'+count+' ' +task+"</h1>");
    -->

    </body>
    </html>

    </pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<head>
  <h1>Список дел</h1>
</head>
<section>
  <input type="text" name="task" id="task" value="Задание">
  <div class="btn-block">
    <button id="add_btn" class="add-task btn">Добавить</button>
    <button id="show_btn" class="show-task btn">Отобразить</button>
  </div>
  <div id="result"> Элемент был добавлен</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  let count = 0;
  $("#add_btn").on('click', function() {
    let task = $("input").val()
    count++;
    $("#result").css("display", "block");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#result").hide()
    }, 2000);
    $('<div>').attr({
      'class': 'add_item'
    }).css({
      'display': 'none'
    }).insertAfter("#result").html("<h1>" + 'Задание #' + count + ' ' + task + "</h1>").appendTo($('.block'));

  });
  $("#show_btn").on('click', function() {
    $(".add_item").css("display", "block");
  });
</script>
```